# Parameterizing Geodesics on the Sphere in Polar Coordinates

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I seem to have this seemingly trivial Problem, but can't figure it out.

**Situation**: 
I have my Unit Sphere, $S^2$ defined as a Riemannian Manifold. Parameterizing Geodesics (Great circles) on this sphere is absolutely no Problem, **IF** I embed it in $\mathbb{R}^3$. **BUT**, I don't want to do this.

What I really want to do, is use riemannian polar coordinates. Now genereally, this isn't a problem, as I could just take any point on the geodesic and call it $(0,0)$ (with $(r,\varphi)$ being my riemannian polar coordinates). And all the lines going through the origin would be my great circles.

*However*, The origin of the exponential map I'm using does not lie on the geodesic of interest. I do however know 2 points (say $P_1, P_2$) and their polar coordinates.

So basically, I have $\text{exp}_p^{-1} : S^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and my two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $(r_1,\varphi_1)$ and $(r_2,\varphi_2)$.

I'm looking for some parameterisation to connect these two points via a great circle. And I just can't think of anything sensible.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit**: To clarify, I have a working method using an $\mathbb{R}^3$ embedding, but it's very bulky and "unpretty".

Further, I'm using this geodesic to "bound" one of my integrals and shifting the Origin is therefore not an option

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean by not wanting to embed $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. You can transform your two points to coordinates in $\mathbb R^3$, find an appropriate rotation to rotate, say, the $x$-$y$-plane into the plane of these points, apply that rotation to the unit circle in the $x$-$y$-plane, and then transform the resulting coordinates back into your polar coordinates. The result would contain no traces of $\mathbb R^3$ and would give you the correct intrinsic coordinates. Are you saying that you want to avoid such an intermediate detour via $\mathbb R^3$?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It would be helpful if you could explain your motivation for trying to do this calculation.

Comment: @joriki, yes, I'm currently trying to avoid the $\mathbb{R}^3$ detour. Currently I'm using that method, but it's far from elegant. @Zhen, my motivation is, that I'm not able to simplify my current approach. It's rather "bulky", and I simply can't work with it. The Formula I'm using takes up roughly an A3-Sheet of paper. I'm hoping a different approach will help me

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use spherical trigonometry? You have a "base triangle" with vertices $O$, $A_1$ and $A_2$, sides $O A_i$ of length $r_i$ and an angle $\alpha:=|\phi_2-\phi_1|$ between them. Now consider an arbitrary point $P$ on the third side $A_1 A_2$. The "line" $OP\ $ has length $r$ and encloses angles $\alpha_i$ with the sides  $OA_i$. The formulas of spherical trigonometry will give you an equation connecting $r$ and the $\alpha_i$.

Let $s_i$ be the lengths of the sides $A_i P$. Then
$$\cos s_i=\cos r_i \cos r +\sin r_i \sin r \cos\alpha_i\qquad(i=1,2)$$
and
$$\cos(s_1+s_2)=\cos r_1\cos r_2+\sin r_1\sin r_2 \cos(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)\ .$$
Eliminate $s_1$ and $s_2$ from these three equations to get the desired result. Hint: Square the identity $\sin s_1 \sin s_2=\cos s_1 \cos s_2-\cos(s_1+s_2)$ and replace $\sin^2 s_i$ by $1-\cos^2 s_i$.

Comment: Thanks! While it does give me some ideas, I still have to find a function that tells me $r$ in dependence of $\alpha_i$. Which brings me to my original problem. I've been looking at the Trigonometry Formulas, but couldn't figure it out, do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Neither approach I propose here are pleasant, but it demonstrates that it can be done in principle.

You can write down an explicit expression for the exponential map in coordinates $(r, \theta) \mapsto (x, y, z)$. If we put the origin of Riemannian polar coordinates at $O = (0, 0, 1)$, then we have $(x, y, z) = (\cos \theta \sin r, \sin \theta \sin r, \cos r)$. You can then try to invert this to obtain expressions for great circles in $(r, \theta)$.

A slightly more clever approach would be to use stereographic projection $\pi : S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \cup \{ \infty \}$:
$$\displaystyle (u, v) = \left( \frac{x}{1-z}, \frac{y}{1-z} \right)$$
So changing to Riemannian polar coordinates, 
$$\displaystyle (u, v) = \left( \frac{\sin r \cos \theta}{1 - \cos r}, \frac{\sin r \sin \theta}{1 - \cos r} \right)$$
we see that 
$$\displaystyle \sqrt{u^2 + v^2} = \frac{\sin r}{1 - \cos r}$$
and the polar angle in the $(u, v)$ plane is equal to $\theta$. We know what the action of $\text{SO}(3)$ on the sphere corresponds to in the $(u, v)$ plane (namely certain Möbius transformations), so we can write down expressions for rotations of the sphere in terms of $(r, \theta)$. (These will probably be quite ugly.) This then allows us to reduce to the case where $P_1 = O$, so we can apply the inverse rotation to get the expression for a great circle through $P_1$ and $P_2$ in Riemannian polar coordinates centred at $O$.

Comment: Thanks for the Input. I've been using a similar approach, and as you said, it isn't very pretty. However, there is a reason I can't simply transform my map so that $P_1 = 0$. I'm using such a geodesic as a boundary for an integral (Integrating over a geodesic triangle). I'm already sitting on one Point ($P_3$ in this case) of this triangle, transforming it would sadly only shift my problem.